# Regex split a string and strip recurring character

Tags: python, regex

Using python I'm parsing several strings. Sometimes the string has appended several semicolons to it.

Example strings:

```
s1="1;Some text"  
s2="2;Some more text;;;;"
```

The number of appending semicolons varies, but if it's there it's never less than two.
The following pattern matches s1, with s2 it includes the appended semicolons.
How do I redo it to remove those?

```
pat=re.compile('(?m)^(\d+);(.*)')
```

Comment: Why are you using multiline mode? It's not necessary for your examples. Can you show an example that has multiple lines so we can see what it looks like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `str.rstrip([chars])`

This method returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

e.g. you can do:

```
s2 = s2.rstrip(";")
```

You can find more information [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Answer (score 1):

```
pat = re.compile(r'\d+;[^;]*')
```